# How to generate DDL for SQL Server tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

I am using SQL server connections in SQL developer using a plug-in. I want to generate DDL for a table present in SQL server connection.

I cannot find any option like SQL in object in view as in ORACLE.

Comment: Can't you use management studio for that?

Comment: But I don't have access to that..is there any other way to go about it?

Comment: You can install management studio on your local computer. It is a free download from Microsoft.

Comment: Hi Peter, as I have said in my earlier reply I don't have any privileges to install as it a company provided lap..is there any other option for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the Data Modeler functionality built into SQL Developer:

- Navigate to: File -> Data Modeler -> Import -> Data Dictionary
- Select the Connect Name for your SQL Server connection and click next
- Select the appropriate Database and/or schema's to import such as the dbo shema of the DB you're interested in
- Click next.
- Select the data base object you want to import (you have multiple tabs to choose from at the bottom) click next.
- Click Finish.

This imports the model info to SQL Data Modeler.  Next you can export the design to DDL:

- Navigate to: File -> Data Modeler -> Export -> DDL File
- Select an Oracle database type such as "Oracle Database 11g" instead of the "SQL Server yyyy" setting.
- Click Generate.
- Select which options you want generated.
- Click OK

The DDL will be generated into the dialog, and you can either copy and paste out of the dialog, or click the save button.